# CakePHP failing to save translation to i18n on save

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, translation, cakephp-2.2

Trying to get my head round CakePHP 2's Translate behaviour and failing at the creation of content step.

We're trying to get translations working based on the subdomain the site is accessed on. So en.example.com will be the English site and fr.example.com the French. The locale is then set in bootstrap by checking the HTTP host:-

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'fr.example.com':
        Configure::write('Config.language', 'fre');
        break;
    case 'en.example.com':
    default:
        Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');
        break;

}
```

I've created the i18n table using the i18n shell script and tested that the above config works for retrieving data if I manually add some translated fields to the table.

We have a page model that we want to translate the title and body of:-

```
class Page extends AppModel {

    public $actsAs = array(
        'Translate' => array(
            'title',
            'body'
        )
    );
```

The idea is that when a page is created on a subdomain we want it to create versions of the page for each language. So if a page is created on en.example.com a French version is created at the same time. I've attempted to do this in the Page::afterSave() method, but it is not saving the alternative translation to the i18n table:

```
public function afterSave($created, $options=array()) {

    parent::afterSave($created, $options);

    if ($created) {

        $this->locale = $this->locale=='eng' ? 'fre' : 'eng';
        $this->save($this->data, false, array('callbacks' => false));

    }

    return;

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, just an idea for the bootstrap part: http://pastebin.com/J8HcVeay That way you can extend it easier when more languages are added :)

Comment: @Jelmer thanks, I was already thinking along those lines. I tried to keep my example code above simple as my issue is with saving translations for all the languages when content is created. My real app is more complicated than two languages, but that's what I'm working against for now until I can get it working.

Comment: What happens when you debug() the `$this->locale` and `$this->data`? Is it even set? Does it even get "inside" of that if-statement? What does the error log say? What happens when you edit instead of create? What is the content of $this->data at all? What is the content of $options, perhaps that is blocking something? Just some questions that might give you some thought :) Did you try the rubber duck method? ;-)

Comment: It definitely gets inside the if statement on saving new content. $this->locale is either 'fre' or 'eng' depending on the domain I save from. $this->data is set, but I've also tried just saving a set array with dummy title and body values; again it didn't save anything. I think I may need to start digging into the core Cake code to see what is going on under-the-hood.